# read and use a local video file in a java web application

Tags: java, file, video

I have a java web application, which uses java servlets, for handling user requests.

I already have my videos on my server, on the location C:\videos\, and I want to show these files on my java web application. I don't want to upload these movies to my web application, since som of them are pretty big, and I want to be able to insert a new drive and use this on my server, in case of lack of disk space, so I can have many more videos in the future.

So my question is, how do I load my movie files into my java web application, so I can show them on my webpage, when they are on the local C drive of the web server?

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup an external context which points to local folder. For the same study about docbase in tomcat.

Also remember doing this means it will be a separate application context.

context name isthe name of xml file

Comment: Can you provide an example or a place where I can read more about how to make an external context, please?

Comment: You will find details more in Q&A like format. because this is a kind of query. http://www.coderanch.com/t/82921/Tomcat/Changing-docbase

Comment: mhh seems like I can't get it to work, I get an 404 error. Does spring framework affect it, since I am using Spring MVC for my request handling?

Comment: This application is based on spring framework?? You mentioned servlets... You need to be bit more clearer on how is you application working. Anyways if you doubt Spring MVC might affect this. Do one thing, in servlet-mapping -> url-pattern -> set value spring/*, using this, all urls which have spring/ appended to it will only be passed via dispatcherServlet, giving you a window to test. Then you can figure out the rest.